# webmoney transfer api in php

Tags: php, currency

I am trying to integrate [webmoney](https://wiki.wmtransfer.com/projects/webmoney/wiki/Web_Merchant_Interface) transfer api to my website. I downloaded the sample code in php, set up the database but when I am executing, it is giving error **"Purse is not activated"**

Also using this method how will I exchange webmoney from buyers webmoney to merchant webmoney.In this example it is just taking static money.

Please help me to integrate this.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should first activate your WM wallet at https://merchant.wmtransfer.com/conf/purses.asp